# Is there a class/variable of karate available to get the details of failed scenarios like failed Scenario name, count etc when run using TestRunner

Tags: karate, junit5

I want to get the details of the failed testcase after running it using TestRunner class. I was able to get few details like error messages, failed count of scenarios and feature files using the Result class of karate.

```
Results results = Runner.path("classpath:errorData/pass.feature").parallel(5);
String errmsgs = results.getErrorMessages();
List<String> err = results.getErrors();
int failcount = results.getFailCount();
```

Now I wanted to know if there is a way to get the details like testcase status, failed scenario, failed step. Any input will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: sorry, I'm new to stackover flow and i didn't know about this feature. I will definitely follow this from next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't find what you need in the `Result` class, please assume the answer is no. Since Karate is open source, you are welcome to figure this out yourself or contribute code for anything missing.